# JavaScript automatically converts some special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I need to extract a HTML-Substring with JS which is position dependent. I store special characters HTML-encoded.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"><p>l&ouml;sen &amp; gr&uuml;&szlig;en</p></div>​
```

**Text**

```
lösen & grüßen
```

My problem lies in the JS-part, for example when I try to extract the fragment
`lö`, which has the HTML-dependent starting position of `3` and the end position of `9` inside the `<div>` block. JS seems to convert some special characters internally so that the count from `3` to `9` is wrongly interpreted as "`lösen` " and not "`l&ouml;`". Other special characters like the `&amp;` are not affected by this.

So my question is, if someone knows why JS is behaving in that way? Characters like `&auml;` or `&ouml;` are being converted while characters like `&amp;` or `&nbsp;` are plain. Is there any possibility to avoid this conversion?

I've set up a fiddle to demonstrate this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66zyK/)

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

Maybe I've explained it a bit confusing, sorry for that. What I want is the HTML:

`<p>l&ouml;sen &amp; gr&uuml;&szlig;en</p>` .

Every special character should be unconverted, except the HTML-Tags. Like in the HTML above.

But JS converts the `&ouml;` or `&uuml;` into `ö` or `ü` automatically, what I need to avoid.

Comment: How are you getting the `lö` fragment? `substr()` seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/66zyK/2/

Comment: so you need to retrieve also the e.g: inner `<p>` tags?

Comment: I need the HTML-Tags as they are, this gives me the formatting of my text. But special characters in the text should be as I store them, HTML-encoded.

Comment: The browser's HTML parser decodes the entities when it constructs the DOM. The original HTML is lost. When you hit `innerHTML` you get a new serialisation of the DOM to HTML.

Comment: Why do you HTML-encode German umlauts? Unicode covers all those characters.

Comment: @Quentin: Link or it didn't happen... ;)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik OP's original demo demonstrates this behavior. Here is a simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/66zyK/3/ As you can see, `.innerHTML` returns the characters, not the original entities.

Comment: @noplacetoh1de Btw, those `&ouml;` things are called "named character references", and are spec'd [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#character-references).

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful informations. I still have the problem, that the ampersand seems to be still HTML-encoded. http://jsfiddle.net/66zyK/5/

Comment: The problem is that I need everything uniformely encoded eg. everything as "named character reference" or everything unicoded, but JS still converts characters like ampersand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use javascript to get raw html code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905219/use-javascript-to-get-raw-html-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the browser (and not JavaScript) turns entities that don't need to be escaped in HTML into their respective Unicode characters (e.g. it skips `&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`).

So by the time you inspect `.innerHTML`, it no longer contains exactly what was in the original page source; you could reverse this process, but it involves the full map of character `<->` entity pairs which is just not practical.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, then try use innerHTML or .html('your html code') for jQuery on the target element