# Getting inner html without escaping or decoding anything with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing some kind of online html editor and I have a problem with getting the content of a textarea with jQuery.

The Textarea element is like this:

```
<textarea id="myText"><b>&lt;p&gt;TEST&lt;/p&gt;</b></textarea>
```

So it is a mixture of escaped and unescaped text. However, the browser shows the textarea like this, which is also something that I don't want :

```
<b><p>TEST</p></b>
```

I want to get the inner html of the textarea as it is. If I try `.html()`, it escapes all the tags and if I try `.val()`, it decodes the escaped tags. You can see the behavior at http://jsfiddle.net/hnBte/

How can I get the pure content with Javascript and optionally, how can I make the textarea show the content as it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this a really interesting question, so I did some research: I tried all javascript and jQuery functions to see what I would get, but nothing worked. You can only get completely unparsed or completely parsed html.

I also stumbled upon this SO-question, that also confirms that, sadly, it just can't be done: [Getting raw text content of HTML element with HTML uninterpreted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419209/getting-raw-text-content-of-html-element-with-html-uninterpreted).

Comment: $("#myText").val( $("#myText").html() );   isn't it what you are looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/WC7gX/1/

Comment: @roasted no it is not. I give mixed(escaped and unescaped) html text and I want to see/get that as it is

Comment: Someone solved this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394787/2057171

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw unfortunately, no... See my updated (and unsuccessfull) JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y2p0fhtd/5/

Answer (score 4):

For anyone asking this in 2021.. My solution was to take the text in place it in a different textarea using `.innerHTML`, then using `document.getElementById("area").textContent` to get the plain text, without encoding or escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.text()` method in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: `.text()` returns the same result as `.val()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the standard JavaScript `.innerHTML`?

Here is a related post about the differences between JavaScript `.innerHTML` and JQuery `.HTML()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/3563136/2099977

Comment: That has the same effect as jQuery's .html()

Comment: `innerHTML` returns the same value as `.html()` while `textContent` returns the decoded form like `.val()`

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this since the browser has already interpreted the mark-up and the raw &lt;p&gt;TEST&lt;/p&gt; values have been converted to html. I think you can only get the whole contents as HTML using `.val()` or the whole contents HTMLencoded using `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the input as the user enters it, or when you load it from an external source.