# Strings being converted/escaped when saving to database with PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, encoding

I am using the Codeigniter PHP framework, and when I save some text to the database using their native method `db->query` the character `&` is becoming `&amp;` when I reload the page and it is inserted in the `textarea` element

what is going on? when I reload, In PHP I am using `db->query` to select rows in the database and `json_encode` to echo the JSON string to the client. In the client side I am using `JSON.parse`

additional info: when I access phpmyadmin to see the content of the table, I can see the `&` char there

@edit

i'm not echoing the JSON in this case. it's not an AJAX situation. i am inserting the encoded JSON to an HTML element, getting the innerHTML property and parsing when the document is loaded

it seems that many browsers have an inbuilt functionality that encodes many chars like <, & etc

please, refere to this
[Answer to "Convert special characters to HTML in Javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784698/993554)

Now what I need is a fix to this. What to do with encoded chars by browsers when we use the innerHTML property in Javascript

Comment: what code you using for generate HTML (native PHP or some HTML helper)? Probably HTML helper escape it.

Comment: hey there. i was mistaken, i am not echoing it. I am actually inserting the json in a hidden HTML element. it seems that the browser has an inbuilt functionality that will escape the chars. weird, now I want to know how to deal with it

i'm not using any helper. i am getting the innerHTML of that element, parsing it with JSON.parse and assigning to `value` of the textarea

Comment: probably it answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252931/getting-inner-html-without-escaping-or-decoding-anything-with-jquery