# Detect whether HTML element contains a specific character entity

Tags: javascript, html-entities, decoding

If I have markup like this:

```
<div id="foo">&#xf067;</div>
```

and I want to detect later whether div#foo still contains that same character entity, I'd like to be able to do so by comparing it to `&#xf067;` rather than to `` (which in my code base is rather obtuse for maintenance purposes).

I've tried things like this (using jQuery):

```
console.log($('<textarea />').html($('#foo').html()).val());
```

But that seems to still output the nice little square "what you talkin' 'bout" character rather than the desired `&#xf067;`.

I'm open to plain JavaScript or jQuery-specific solutions.

Comment: How about `console.log($('#foo').html())` ?? (I guess you may only get back entities for HTML-relevant metacharacters.) In any case you can form a JavaScript string with that character in it very easily: `"\uF067"`

Comment: Doesn't look like you can get the raw data as you want it, [see here for info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419209/getting-raw-text-content-of-html-element-with-html-uninterpreted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Unicode entity in JavaScript. For example:

(HTML: `<div id='foo'>&#xf067;</div>`)

JavaScript:

```
console.log($('#foo').html().charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
  //=> f067
console.log($('#foo').html().indexOf('\uf067'));
  //=> 0
```

[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/L5jhx0tj/1/)