# Test for special & html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I set a span using:

```
<span id=\"xxx\">&#9656;</span>
```

Can someone tell me why the following test doesn't work:

```
if ($("#xxx").text() == "&#9656;")
         alert("hello");
```

Comment: This might also be informative: [Getting raw text content of HTML element with HTML uninterpreted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419209/getting-raw-text-content-of-html-element-with-html-uninterpreted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use the other answer that make a direct symbol condition `$("#xxx").text() == "▸"` and you want to check the span text `&#9656;`, you could use `.charCodeAt(0)` to get the special symbole number then add `&#` and `;` in your condition :

```
var special_symbol_number = $("#xxx").text().charCodeAt(0);

if ( "&#"+special_symbol_number+";" === "&#9656;")
  alert("hello");
```

Or you could check just with special symbol number as :

```
if ($("#xxx").text().charCodeAt(0) === '9656')
    alert("hello");
```

Hopet this helps.

```js
if ($("#xxx").text().charCodeAt(0) === '9656')
  alert("hello");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="xxx">9656</span>
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but I think this might be a bit cleaner: if ($("#xxx").text().charCodeAt(0) == "9656")

Comment: Actually Yes I agree with Ben I think the code is sufficicent

Comment: Ok @MarMan29 i've added the proper condition also to the answer.. good luck.

Answer (score 3):

because `&#9656;` is actually this character `▸`

When you do `$('#xxx').text()` you'll get `▸`

Try doing it this way:

```
if ($("#xxx").text() == "▸")
     alert("hello");
```

From looking at the other questions linked in this one. Looks like the way to do what you're looking for is:

```
if ($("#xxx").text().charCodeAt() == '9656')
     alert("hello");
```

Comment: how do you test for &#9656;

Answer (score 1):

"&#9656‌;" is a that applies *only* to HTML and not to the Javascript. In HTML its' called an [Entity](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), and it gets replaced with the literal character (▸). But it doesn't do this in JavaScript.

To check for the character in JavaScript, just put character in literally:

```
if ($("#xxx").text() == "▸")
    alert("hello");
```

You can get the character by copying it in your browser (select the ▸, and hit cmd-c or ctrl-c), and then pasting it in the JavaScript file.

The reason HTML uses entities is because it has some characters (like < and >) that can be parsed as actual parts of the code (try writing <text> in HTML; it won't be visible because HTML thinks you want an element); the entities allow these values to be parsed literally even when they look like code. Here is a working snippet, where the JavaScript successfully checks the contents of the element:

```js
if ($("#xxx").text() == "▸")
    alert("hello");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="xxx">&#9656;</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can do this:

```
<span id=\"xxx\">&amp;#9656;</span>

if ($("#xxx").text() == "&#9656;")
     alert("hello");
```

Comment: The browser will not render the special character this way

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to check "&#9656;" not the literal character.

Comment: yes this is correct, but the ▸ icon will not be displayed on the frontend anymore. It will literally display `&#9656;` on the frontend

Comment: I saw OP's question "how do you test for &#9656; ". in one of the comments above,this led me post my answer and besides I do not have enough reputation to post comment so I can confirm with him