# How can I remove an XML attribute\namespace from a tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following problem. I have an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transfer xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" username="my_username" password="my_pswd">
    <providerpid>00AB40</providerpid>
    <recipientpid>00AD12</recipientpid>
    <symbol>SMTA1234</symbol>
    <type>SMTA</type>
    <materials>
        <doi>10.0155/1463</doi>
        <doi>10.0155/1464</doi>
    </materials>
</transfer>
```

As you can see the  element have this attribute setted **xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"**

How can I remove this attribute using simple JavaScript?

Comment: `elem.removeAttribute('xmlns')` but why would you do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766291/removing-xmlns-attributes-added-automatically

Comment: @selvassn in linked question the attribute was added **automatically** because the markup was recognized as being [x]html. While in current case, the attribute is harcoded into the xml.