# Get exact html() with closing tag for which starting tag is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently for a body with HTML: `hello</div><p>hai</p><span>Welcome</span>` on alerting `$('body').html()` it alerts `hello<p>hai</p><span>Welcome</span>`.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B77qj/)

But I want it to display `hello</div><p>hai</p><span>Welcome</span>` **i.e.** Alert HTML as it is written within the body.

I can see the exact code when I view the source-code of the page.I really dont know if client-side scripts are capable of displaying the output I asked.

***Is it possible ?And if yes How?***

Comment: If you write invalid code, you can't expect the browser to return it to you as it will try to fix your mistakes and remove the closing tag that has no place being there. By the time javascript runs that tag has been removed, so you won't be able to get it.

Comment: @adeneo yes I can write the correct HTML while developing an application.But my question is can I detect missing start tags

Comment: fix the div tags, why alert rather than console.log - your question does not say you want a lint checker :)

Comment: Would `jquery.load()` return the broken divs?

Comment: @Zword - Nope, the browser fixes those mistakes automatically, so the closing tag is removed from the DOM. The only way you could get it would be to get the file as text and parse it in some way yourself, but that doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Sorry there is no solution

Comment: When you say "I can see the exact code when I view the source-code of the page.", are you saying the closing `</div>` is there in the source?

Comment: And by the why would you alert() the code which has missing paranthesis?

Comment: @adeneo you are telling get the file contents and check them to detect closing tags?

Comment: @gtr1971 - Why wouldn't it be? The source and the DOM are two different things.

Comment: @Zword - As the DOM is changed by the browser when it tries to fix mistakes in the markup, you surely can't get it from there, so the only thing I can think of is getting the content of the file with an XMLHttpRequest and parse that content yourself.

Comment: ^^ Using $.get maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/bYWkP/show/

Comment: @A.Wolff well that can help I guess.Can you post an answer?

Comment: @Zword You may already know this but $.get == AJAX == XMLHttpRequest  They are all synonyms for ajax (as are $.post and $.load also). Note that $.get, $.post and $.load are shortcuts to specific types of AJAX implementations.

Comment: Why don't you just validate your HTML? [W3C.org Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use javascript to get raw html code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905219/use-javascript-to-get-raw-html-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an ajax request, this way the HTML won't be parsed:

```
$.get(window.location.href,function(data){console.log(data);});
```

[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bYWkP/1/)

Comment: This does give me the whole script but can I store `data` in a variable?

Comment: @Zword What do you think `data` is?

Comment: Nice insight into JSFIDDLE, does not return the whole Fiddle HTML, and on `Run` again, parses an object as string...

Comment: @Zword Yes, you can store it in a global variable, however, it doesn't make any sense to do so because ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: `window.foo = data` Good luck using it though.

Comment: It works, just not the way you want it to. It's not going to work the way you want it to ***because ajax is asynchronous***

Comment: @A.Wolff +1 for helping