# Why does innerHTML behaves differently when it has <html> as a content?

Tags: html, dom, browser

Can anyone tell me why  special here?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="editor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scripts" class="scripts">
            Editor.Execute('<html>Html String</html>');
            Editor.Execute('<something>Html String</something>');
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`document.getElementById("scripts").innerHTML` shows `something` however `html` dissapears.

```
    Execute('Html String');
    Execute('<something>Html String</something>');
```

It behaves the same way in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: what does that statement return (whats the result from innerHTML) ?

Comment: So it treats something different from html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905503/2694328).

Basically, the browser sanitizes out the HTML tags before your JavaScript can even access the page – you can check in the Chrome elements inspector, your `<html>` tag is not there.

I guess the answer depends on what exactly you're trying to do, but if you're just trying to output that code onto a web page, you can just escape the characters:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="scripts" class="scripts">
            Execute('&lt;html&gt;Html String&lt;/html&gt;');
            Execute('&lt;something&gt;Html String&lt;/something&gt;');
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then `document.getElementById('scripts').innerHTML` will output:

```
Execute('&lt;html&gt;Html String&lt;/html&gt;');
Execute('&lt;something&gt;Html String&lt;/something&gt;');
```

And then you can replace the HTML entities in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I am aware of escaping.However, I was just curious to see why <html> was behaving differently. <body> also behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you do in that `Execute()` it is hard to say what is going on there.

Just in case: HTML document can have one and only one `<html>` node.

Comment: I have modified the code. Its for a HTML Editor that takes pure HTML as input. So I am just executing it after the page loads. I think the HTML goes into another Iframe.